# Div width gradually increases when the window width decrease (w/ media queries)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

is it possible to make that a div width increase when the window width decrease without media queries ?

For example, a div which take 50% of the width when the screen is 1920 pixels large and 80% when it's 800 pixels and the percentage width gradually increases.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is:

```
div.myWidth{
    width:calc( 1vw * 0.25 + 480px );
}
```

or

```
div.myWidth{
    width:calc( 1vw / 4 + 480px );
}
```

It exacty matches your calculation, no media query involved. CSS3 is, however, a prerequisite.

Also please note, that the absolute div width does not increase, only its percentage of the width does increase. Your question was a little bit contradictory in that.

However, once you reached down to 480px, the div would fill up the entire space. Below 480px, the div would stretch beyond the right border of the window, so you might want to constrain that:

```
div.myWidth{
    width:calc( 1vw / 4 + 480px );
    max-width:1vw;
}
```

Comment: how the width will increase if the window decrease? .. the vw will decrease and the overall calculation will decrease also

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's why I said it's contradictory. The OP states: _and the **percentage** width gradually increases._ But given his examples, you'll see that there, the width actually also decreases. I guess he wants the percentage to increase, not the actual width (as I wrote in my answer)

Comment: Thank you it works but I don't understand why you divide by four in your calcul

Comment: Because that's math ;) I just noticed that your examples take into account 25% of the window width, added to a fixed value of 480px.